# Print the sentences with least number of vowels in R

Tags: r, string

I have a long set of sentences and I need to print the sentences with the least number of vowels. Use the following code I found the least number of vowels, there are several sentences with that least number of vowels. When I use str_view_all to display the sentences I need to use a pattern in the argument. If I do it the following way, it only displays 1 sentence.

```
sentences[min(str_count(sentences, "[aeiou]"))]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could proceed this way:

First determine how many vowels each sentence has by counting the characters after removing anything that is not a vowel

```
vowels = nchar(str_remove_all(sent,"[^aeiou]"))
```

Then get the minimum number of vowels and which sentences have that value:

```
sentences[vowels==min(vowels)]
```

This will give you:

```
 [1] "Adding fast leads to wrong sums."      
 [2] "A fresh start will work such wonders." 
 [3] "Ducks fly north but lack a compass."   
 [4] "Time brings us many changes."          
 [5] "Boards will warp unless kept dry."     
 [6] "Glass will clink when struck by metal."
 [7] "Each penny shone like new."            
 [8] "Our plans right now are hazy."         
 [9] "North winds bring colds and fevers."   
[10] "Xew pants lack cuffs and pockets."     
[11] "Paper will dry out when wet."          
[12] "Lush fern grow on the lofty rocks."    
[13] "Hang tinsel from both branches."
```

Looking at your question, you were close to the answer:

```
sentences[ str_count(sentences, "[aeiou]") == min(str_count(sentences, "[aeiou]")) ]
```

Comment: why is the ^ in [^aeiou] necessary?

Comment: @JakeParker it negates the letters inside the []. This means anything that is not an a,e,i,o,u

Answer (score 2):

Here's a `stringr` option:

```
library(stringr)
sentences[which.min(str_count(sentences, "[aeiou]"))]
[1] "I am happy."
```

How this works:

- First, `str_count` counts the number of vowels in each string.
- Then, `which.min` finds the index of the string with the smallest number of vowels.
- Finally, `sentences[...]` subsets the vector on that string that has the index of the string with the smallest number of vowels.

Data (from @ThomasIsCoding):

```
sentences <- c("I am happy.", "What's up, man?", "I am from Russia.")
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R option using `gsub` + `nchar` + `min`

```
sentences[(cnt <- nchar(gsub("[^aeiou]", "", sentences))) == min(cnt)]
```

which gives

```
[1] "I am happy."
```

**Data**

```
sentences <- c("I am happy.", "What's up, man?", "I am from Russia.")
```

Answer (score 1):

We can also use

```
 i1 <- str_count(sentences, '[aeious]')
 sentences[i1 == min(i1)]
 #[1] "I am happy."
```

#### data

```
sentences <- c("I am happy.", "What's up, man?", "I am from Russia.")
```